# Is there a way to extract start and end from a TimeWeightSummary - Timescaledb

Tags: postgresql, timescaledb, weighted

I'm using the **time_weight** function from **timescaledb** in a SQL Query. From the [doc](https://docs.timescale.com/api/latest/hyperfunctions/time-weighted-averages/time_weight/#advanced-usage-notes) time_weight is defined as:

> An aggregate that produces a **TimeWeightSummary** from timestamps and associated values.

Also in the doc we can read

> Internally, the first and last points seen as well as the calculated weighted sum are stored in each TimeWeightSummary

Is there a way to extract the first and the last point value and timestamp from this TimeWeightSummary ?

Here is my SQL query:

```
WITH t as (
    SELECT
        time_bucket('1 hour'::interval, time) as dt,
        time_weight('Linear', time, p) AS tw
    FROM tsdb.asset_sensor_sample
    WHERE asset = 16
    GROUP BY time_bucket('1 hour'::interval, time)
)
SELECT
    dt,
    tw,   
    average(tw) -- extract the average from the time weight summary
FROM t LIMIT 5;
```

Here is the result:

```
           dt           |                                                                                              tw                                                                                              |      average       
------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------
 2022-06-20 10:00:00+00 | (version:1,first:(ts:"2022-06-20 10:15:43.274976+00",val:127334.29194694175),last:(ts:"2022-06-20 10:55:43.274976+00",val:54155.74946698491),weighted_sum:239731880571173.1,method:Linear)   |  99888.28357132213
 2022-06-20 11:00:00+00 | (version:1,first:(ts:"2022-06-20 11:05:43.274976+00",val:72054.79620663091),last:(ts:"2022-06-20 11:55:43.274976+00",val:117667.04302813657),weighted_sum:247386550516233.63,method:Linear)  |   82462.1835054112
 2022-06-20 12:00:00+00 | (version:1,first:(ts:"2022-06-20 12:05:43.274976+00",val:95982.76112628987),last:(ts:"2022-06-20 12:55:43.274976+00",val:83790.58995691259),weighted_sum:259849005747598.72,method:Linear)   |  86616.33524919958
 2022-06-20 13:00:00+00 | (version:1,first:(ts:"2022-06-20 13:05:43.274976+00",val:108062.03874288549),last:(ts:"2022-06-20 13:55:43.274976+00",val:117030.17726887773),weighted_sum:329446374963518.94,method:Linear) | 109815.45832117298
 2022-06-20 14:00:00+00 | (version:1,first:(ts:"2022-06-20 14:05:43.274976+00",val:64564.42379745973),last:(ts:"2022-06-20 14:55:43.274976+00",val:95290.48787317045),weighted_sum:303986848836652.75,method:Linear)   | 101328.94961221758
(5 rows)
```

We can clearly see that these informations are available in the tw column. But I don't know to extract it.

Comment: There isn't an easy way right now, but it sounds like we should be exposing it if it's something you want! Would you mind filing an issue here: https://github.com/timescale/timescaledb-toolkit/issues ?